# Vue-router component reusing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

*I would like to know how can I stop component reusing in Vue-router.*

I'm building a simple page application and I am unable to **update data after clicking the same link twice.**

Is it possible to somehow force reloading or what are the best practices in my situation?

Answer (score 15):

Use the `key` attribute on `router-view` set to current url. It's built in, so no need to write any code.

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Comment: Does this mean that every component is always re-rendered on a route change?

Comment: Whole view is rerendered when path (URL) changes.

Answer (score 5):

Vue Router reuses the same component therefore the mounted hook won't be called. As stated in the documentation:

> The same component instance will be reused [...] the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.

If you want to update the data you have two options:

- Watch the $route object

```js
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

- Use the beforeRouteUpdate navigation guard

```js
const User = {
  template: '...',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // react to route changes...
    // don't forget to call next()
  }
}
```

For a more detailed explanation you can check the section Reacting to Param Changes of the Vue Router documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to put a key on the `router-view` and append a timestamp querystring to your `router-link`

```js
const Home = {
    template: '<div>Home</div>',
    created() {
        console.log('This should log everytime you click home.');
    },
};

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
    ]
});

new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <router-link :to="`/?q=${Date.now()}`">/home</router-link>
  <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
</div>
```

One reason not to do it this way is because it'll force rerenders on components that you may want to be reused such as on routes like

- `/posts/1`
- `/posts/2`

Comment: Just to clarify... What about when I send a request to delete a post from another device to my API and meanwhile I have opened all posts on another device? Expected behavior(at least in my case ) is when I click on the same link again data should reload. But nothing happens.

Comment: @user8540556 Is your data stored local to the component or in vuex?  Is the `GET` request sent in the component or elsewhere?

Comment: It's stored locally. Request is sent in mounted() method in component.

Comment: @user8540556 Do you see the request being sent again when the link is clicked?  If so, is the returned data correct?