# Why does the browser display cached Vue.js view on route/url change?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a homepage with `<router-link>` tags to views. It is a simple master/detail relationship where the `Homepage` is a catalogue of products and the `Product` detail page/view shows information on each item.

When I first launch the website and click on an item on the `Homepage` view (e.g. URL: `http://localhost:8080/100-sql-server-2019-licence`), the `Product` view gets loaded and the product detail loads fine.

If I then press the back button in the browser to return to the `Homepage` and then click on a different `Product` (e.g. URL: `http://localhost:8080/101-oracle-12c-licence`), the URL in the browser address bar changes but I get the previous product's information. Its lightning quick and no new network calls are done which means its just showing a cached page of the previous product. If I then hit the refresh button while on that page, the network call is made and the correct product information is displayed.

I did a search online but couldn't find this problem described on the search results. Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to cause a refresh/re-render of a route when the route changes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What is happening

`vue-router` will cache your components by default.
So when you navigate to the second product (that probably renders the same component as the first product), the component will **not** be instantiated again for performance reasons.

From the [`vue-router` documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards):

> For example, for a route with dynamic params `/foo/:id`, when we
>   navigate between `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, the same `Foo` component instance
>   will be reused.

#### The easy (but dirty) fix

The easy -but hacky and not recommended - way to solve this is to give your `<router-view />` a key property, e.g.:

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
```

This will force `vue-router` to re-instantiate the view component every time the url changes.
However you will loose all performance benefits you would normally get from the caching.

#### Clean fix: properly handling route changes

The clean way to solve this problem is to react to the route-change in your component (mostly this boils down to moving ajax calls from `mounted` into a `$route` watcher), e.g.:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      productDetails: null,
      loading: false
    };
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': {
      // with immediate handler gets called on first mount aswell
      immediate: true,
      // handler will be called every time the route changes.
      // reset your local component state and fetch the new data you need here.
      async handler(route) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.productDetails = null;
        try {
          // example for fetching your product data
          const res = await fetch("http://give.me.product.data/" + encodeURIComponent(route.params.id));
          this.productDetails = await res.json();
        } finally {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

#### Alternative: Navigation Guards

Alternatively you could also use `vue-router`s [In-Component Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to react to route changes:

```html
<script>
export default {
  async beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // TODO: The route has changed.
    // The old route is in `from`, the new route in `to`.
    this.productData = await getProductDataFromSomewhere();

    // route will not change before you haven't called `next()`
    next();
  }
};
</script>
```

- The downside of the navigation guards is that you can only use them directly in the component that the route renders.
  So you **can't** use navigation guards in components deeper within the hierarchy.
- The upside is that the browser will not view your site before you call `next()`, which gives you time to load the data necessary before your route is displayed.

#### Some helpful ressources

- [Vue Router Navigation Guards Documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)
- [`vue-router` github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1490)
- [Similar Question about `vue-router` component reuse on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52505126/8411406)

Comment: interesting, thank you. Can you explain why `AppPage` component DOES work properly when theyre different routes? Is it because its cached PER route in router/index.js?